# Create a new column with condition if a string 'contains' substring?

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to add a new column 'check' with the following condition:

- 'Suppression total' and 'Sup-SDM'.

OR

- Suppression partiel and Franc SUP - Geisi

**Dataframe**:

| Type | Info |
| --- | --- |
| Sup_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression totale |
| Modif_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Creation |
| Sup_EF - SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression totale |
| Modif_EF - Franc SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-17 10:50:40.0-Suppression partiel |

**Desired output**:

| Type | Info | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sup_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression total | Correct |
| Modif_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Creation | Fail |
| Sup_EF - SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression total | Fail |
| Modif_EF - Franc SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-17 10:50:40.0-Suppression partiel | Correct |

**Code**:

```
if ('SUP - SDM' in df["Type"].values) and ('Suppression total' in df['Info'].values):
    df['Check'] = "Correct"
elif ('Franc SUP - Geisi' in df["Type"].values) and ('Suppression partiel' in df['Info'].values):
    df['Check'] = "Correct"
else:
    df['Check'] = "Fail"
```

But my output looks like this:

| Type | Info | Check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sup_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression total | Fail |
| Modif_EF - SUP - SDM | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Creation | Fail |
| Sup_EF - SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-08 16:47:51.0-Suppression total | Fail |
| Modif_EF - Franc SUP - Geisi | 2021-12-17 10:50:40.0-Suppression partiel | Fail |

Answer (score 0):

This apply approach can be slow for very large datasets, but is good for general purposes

```
df['Check'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Correct' if ('Suppression total' in x['Info'] and 'Sup-SDM' in x['Type']) or ('Suppression partiel' in x['Info'] and 'Franc SUP - Geisi' in x['Type']) else 'Fail')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it shows KeyError: Info

Comment: can you show what `df.columns` returns @Cherrycherry